# Query real time heart rate variability and heart rate values

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm trying to read out real time heart rate + heart rate variability data from the apple watch. 
I am able to read the heartRate value but don't know how to implement the reading of the HRV. I it possible to have them read out simultaneously ?

```
class HealthKitManager {

    private var healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    private var heartRateQuantity = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
    private var heartRateVariability = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
    private var activeQueries = [HKQuery]()

    @Published var heartRateValues = HeartRateValues()

    func autorizeHealthKit() {

        let heartRate = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!
        let heartRateVariability = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!

        let HKreadTypes: Set = [heartRate, heartRateVariability]

        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: HKreadTypes) { (success, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error requesting health kit authorization: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchHeartRateData(quantityTypeIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier ) {

        let devicePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: [HKDevice.local()])
        let updateHandler: (HKAnchoredObjectQuery, [HKSample]?, [HKDeletedObject]?, HKQueryAnchor?, Error?) -> Void = {
        query, samples, deletedObjects, queryAnchor, error in
            guard let samples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
                return
            }
            self.process(samples, type: quantityTypeIdentifier)
        }
        let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: quantityTypeIdentifier)!, predicate: devicePredicate, anchor: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, resultsHandler: updateHandler)
        query.updateHandler = updateHandler
        healthStore.execute(query)
        activeQueries.append(query)
    }

    private func process(_ samples: [HKQuantitySample], type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
        for sample in samples {
            if type == .heartRate {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.heartRateValues.heartRate = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: self.heartRateQuantity)
                }
            } 
                // Not Sure about this part and readings show 0.0
                else if type == .heartRateVariabilitySDNN {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.heartRateValues.heartRateVariability = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: self.heartRateVariability)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopFetchingHeartRateData() {
        activeQueries.forEach { healthStore.stop($0) }
        activeQueries.removeAll()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heartRateValues.heartRate = 0.0
            self.heartRateValues.heartRateVariability = 0.0
        }

    }

}
```

A comparable question was asked here but it didn't receive an answer: 
[Get Apple watch heartRateVariabilitySDNN realtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081308/get-apple-watch-heartratevariabilitysdnn-realtime)

Comment: Duplicating a question isn't appreciated. You could upvote that other question or put up a Bounty to attract viewers and answers there.

Comment: It's not completely the same question. I am wondering if it's possible to have them both queried at the same time, and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the hrs reading as well, just added:

```
private func process(_ samples: [HKQuantitySample], type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
    for sample in samples {
        if type == .heartRate {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.heartRateValues.heartRate = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: self.heartRateQuantity)
            }
        } else if type == .heartRateVariabilitySDNN {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.heartRateValues.heartRateVariability = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: self.heartRateVariabilityQuantity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then call the class with:

```
    fetchHeartRateData(quantityTypeIdentifier: .heartRate)
    fetchHeartRateData(quantityTypeIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)
```

Problem remains the HRV value get's read once, and doesn't change over time. Any ideas ?